# Unhandled rejection Error with Bookshelf and async

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, bluebird, bookshelf.js

I have an issue with Unhandled rejection Error when throwing an error in an on saving hook in Bookshelf. Bookshelf has a [custom event handler](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/blob/master/src/base/events.js#L98) that works with Promises for events, and an [extended version of Bluebird](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/blob/c872a96c20616a18eb6aa47e361b6ec82b2d7269/src/base/promise.js) for Promises.

```
'use strict'

const knex = require('./src/knex')
const Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')
const bookshelf = Bookshelf(knex)

class MyModel extends bookshelf.Model {
  get tableName () {
    return 'my_table'
  }

  initialize () {
    bookshelf.Model.prototype.initialize.call(this)

    this.on('saving', () => {
      throw new Error('Some validation')
    })
  }
}

async function main () {
  try {
    await bookshelf.transaction(async (trx) => {
      return MyModel
        .forge({
          id: 0,
        })
        .save(null, {
          patch: true,
          transacting: trx,
        })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

main()
```

This is the output:

```
knex:tx trx1: Starting top level transaction +0ms
Unhandled rejection Error: Some validation
  at MyModel.on (/test.js:18:13)
  at /node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/events.js:176:25
From previous event:
  at MyModel.triggerThen (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/events.js:175:32)
  at MyModel.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:1045:19)
From previous event:
  at MyModel.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:970:8)
From previous event:
  at bookshelf.transaction (/test.js:30:10)
  at /node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:81:20
  at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
From previous event:
  at /node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:75:10
  at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
From previous event:
  at new Transaction (/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:68:41)
  at Client_PG.transaction (/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:158:12)
  at Object.transaction (/node_modules/knex/lib/util/make-knex.js:75:21)
  at Object.transaction (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:247:36)
  at main (/test.js:25:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/test.js:40:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:598:3

knex:tx trx1: releasing connection +55ms
Error: Some validation
  at MyModel.on (/test.js:18:13)
  at /node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/events.js:176:25
From previous event:
  at MyModel.triggerThen (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/events.js:175:32)
  at MyModel.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:1045:19)
From previous event:
  at MyModel.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:970:8)
From previous event:
  at bookshelf.transaction (/test.js:30:10)
  at /node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:81:20
  at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
From previous event:
  at /node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:75:10
  at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
  at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
From previous event:
  at new Transaction (/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:68:41)
  at Client_PG.transaction (/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:158:12)
  at Object.transaction (/node_modules/knex/lib/util/make-knex.js:75:21)
  at Object.transaction (/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/bookshelf.js:247:36)
  at main (/test.js:25:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/test.js:40:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:598:3
```

The error disappears when I remove `async` from `await bookshelf.transaction(async (trx) => {`. I know the async here is unnecessary, but I'm curious why this causes the rejection to be unhandled?

---

**Edit 1**

I fail to replicate the error without Bookshelf.

```
async function main () {
  try {
    await test1()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

async function test1 () {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    throw new Error('Some validation')
  })
}

main()
```

This does not generate an unhandled rejection.

---

**Edit 2**

```
async function main () {
  try {
    await test2()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

async function test2 () {
  return Promise.map([
    (() => {
      throw new Error('Some validation')
    })()
  ])
}
```

This does not generate an unhandled rejection.

Comment: Well don't `throw new Error('Some validation')` in asynchronous event handlers.

Comment: @Bergi I added an edit to the question. Throwing an error usually works with asynchronous code.

Comment: That's an exception in a promise `then` callback, where they are caught and lead to a rejection, not an exception in an arbitrary asynchronous callback.

Comment: @Bergi I added another edit without the then callback, to simulate [what happens here](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/blob/master/src/base/events.js#L98), but still can't recreate the issue.

Comment: Throwing an exception in an `async function` is the same as rejecting a promise.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for trying to explain, but I don't really understand the underlying issue, and don't know how to recreate it without Bookshelf.

Comment: Oops, forget my comments. I totally overread "*Bookshelf has a custom event handler that works with Promises for events*", so apparently this *should* work. My first conclusion would be that `bookshelf.transaction` doesn't correctly handle the rejection, but then again it actually does (which leads to the second log entry for the error) and also your observation that it works without the `async` function is weird. My guess then would be that Bluebird's unhandled rejection detection doesn't work correctly in the presence of `async`/`await` due to the mix with native promises.